# Track MySQL schema and procedures change

Tags: mysql

Recently I changed some table schema and procedures in DEV environment. Before i deploy it to production environment, I want to have a change list.

How to track or show the schema and procedures change history in MySQL? For example, show which tables have been changed after 2011-06-10, which procedures have been created or updated after 2011-06-08.

Comment: What about checking the history file on the client used to make the changes?  Presumably, you have very few users making such schema changes :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a longer route, but, you could you create a [data dictionary](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/06/using-data-dictionary.html). You can date them, and then represent the different schema version, or even changes to the schema. They are easily tracked with your favorite version control tool.

Answer (score 0):

information_schema tables have create date fields which would get you a list of added tables and procedures etc after a particular date but modifications can't be identified by this method. However, a much simpler method would be to restore a prod backup to a different name and then use the [mysqldiff utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldiff.html) to identify the changes.